# phonegap api call not working

Tags: ajax, cordova

I have a rails api running on localhost:3000. On my phonegap app i'm trying to login via api , but it give an error("error") and don't reach to the api.
could be some problem with cross domain request, but is said that in the mobile there is no such thing. internet  is working .

my ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'localhost:3000/api/v1/login',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data : {username:"demo",password:"demo"},
        success: function(data) {
           navigator.notification.alert("ok");
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              console.log("Error status " + status);
        }
});
```

EDIT 2 - solved

You have to to use local ip eg. 192.168.2.2
and add the host in the Cordova.plist in the ExternalHosts key.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using "localhost" when you run this code on a device/emulator then "localhost" refers to the device/emulator itself and not the web server that contains your rails API. You'll need to switch "localhost" to the IP address or hostname of your server.